# ofstream ifilestream and using cin to get an array of chars?

Tags: c++, stl, filesystems, filestream

So I am learning how to use streams to make files of my own type, I have a simple version of it working like this

```
struct Appointment
{

Appointment()
{

}
// 

//and int to represent a certain doctor
int doctorID;  // an enum to be made later

int year; // 1950 - 2050    100 years total

int month; // 0 - 11  

int day; // 0 - 31   

int hour; // 0 - 23


int minute; // 0 - 59
    static Appointment GetDataFromUser()
{
    Appointment appoint = Appointment();

    cout << "\nEnter a Doctor ID :" << endl;
    cin >> appoint.doctorID;

    cout << "\nEnter a year 1900 - 3000 :" << endl;
    cin >> appoint.year;

    cout << "\nEnter a month 0 - 11 :" << endl;
    cin >> appoint.month;

    cout << "\nEnter a day of month 0 - 31 :" << endl;
    cin >> appoint.day;

    cout << "\nEnter an hour 0 - 23 :" << endl;
    cin >> appoint.hour;

    cout << "\nEnter an minute 0 - 59 :" << endl;
    cin >> appoint.minute;

    cout << "\nAll values entered thank you!" << endl;

    return appoint;

}
};
```

then somewhere I use

```
ifstream ifilestream( fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios::binary );

Appointment appoint;

ifilestream.read((char *)&appoint, sizeof(Appointment));
```

and

```
ofstream ofilestream( fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios::binary );

Appointment appoint = Appointment::GetDataFromUser();

ofilestream.write((char *)&appoint, sizeof(Appointment));
```

This works ok but I want to replace the int doctorID  with a char doctorID[ length ]   length could = 20 or something, to store the doctors name with spaces and .  For example a user could enter "Dr. Watson"  or just "Watson".

But when I do and use cin to get that info it breaks the code cause of spaces or whatever I'm not sure.  So whats the proper way to do that?

And a second question is, what if i wanted the length of the char[] to be decided when the user enters it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To input a string that contains spaces, use `cin.getline()`, which reads up to a newline:

```
char doctorID[20]; 
...
cout << "\nEnter a Doctor ID :" << endl;
cin.getline(appoint.doctorID, 20);
```

If you want a string whose size is determined at runtime, you should use `std::string`, which can be dynamically resized.

However, if you use `std::string`, you will no longer be able to read and write your structure to/from file the way you do now. (*) You can either:

1. Switch to a text-based file
   format
2. Write your own functions
   for serializing/deserializing an
   `std::string` to a binary file
3. Use a serialization library like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/)

(*) because right now you're just writing the structure exactly as it is represented in memory; however std::string's representation is really just a pointer to another memory location

Comment: when i use cin.getline(appoint.doctorID, 20);  it just moves on to the next cin and doesn't let me enter anything leaving it blank?

Comment: If you do `cin.getline()` after a formatted cin operation (`cin >> something`), the newline from the formatted operation will still be in the input buffer and `cin.getline()` just reads that rather than your new line. Call `cin.get()` to get rid of it, and then call `cin.getline()`.

Comment: question, after I use cin.getline(appoint.doctorID, 100)  could I get the length of that char[] store than in a variable, and write it to file just before the char[] and then when I read from the file I could multiply that length by the size of a char and now I know the length of the char[].    Would that work and make it determined at run time?

Comment: Yes, you could use `strlen()` (from `<cstring>`) to get the actual length of the string after reading it into a char array; however you are still using a fixed buffer (100 characters in this case) which has the disadvantages that 1) if the string is much less than 100 characters, you are wasting space, and 2) if the string is more than 100 characters (unlikely, but possible), you are out of luck. For this reason I would still recommend you use `std::string` instead. [continued in next comment due to character limit]

Comment: If you use `std::string` (from the `<string>` header), you would read the input string using `getline(cin, s)` where `s` is your `std::string` variable. The string would be automatically resized to whatever length necessary, and you can call `size()` to get its length.

Comment: As far as writing the string's length to file before the string itself and then reading it so you know how many characters to read, yes you can do that with either a char array or `std::string`. This is what I had in mind when I said option 2, "write your own functions for serializing/deserializing a string to a binary file". Just be careful as this sort of code can be tricky to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinterpret your struct as a data pointer! This binds it to whatever in-memory representation your current compiler produces. If you ever change anything about your program, your streaming would break.

For output, the first step is to write an `operator<<(ostream& out, Appointment const& app);` function. Generally you want this to be a free function that is a friend of your class

```
struct Appointment
{
    // previous contents
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Appointment const& app);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Appointment const& app)
{
    out << app.doctorID << std::endl;
    // out << app.OtherField for each field
    return out;
}
```

Then you can `ofilestream << appoint;`. Write the symmetric operator for input, but you can ignore the whitespace. Use std::string instead of char[].
The most generic solution for serialization would be to use the boost::Serialization framework. But it is overkill for this problem.

Comment: I want to do binary representations.  Because I'm making my own file formats and opening/writing/modifying other binary formats that I didn't make.

Comment: Then open your ofstream in binary mode. `ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.bin", ios::out | ios::binary); `

Comment: Maybe this will illustrate the problem clearer:
How are you able to guarantee that the compiler lays out the struct in memory the exact same way every time you compile it? If you want this guarantee, you need to provide more information to the compiler than you currently are. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx